# How to change language dropdown button image in react after dropdown menu link is clicked?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn react so as an exercise I'm trying to convert a static html website I built a while ago into react.
The website has content in two languages: English and German.
I created a custom dropdown element that contains a button with an image of US flag that toggles the dropdown menu, and a dropdown menu which itself contains two links: first one for the English and the other for German version of the website, each containing image of a flag and a span which names the language.
I'm using react router inside my Layout component to navigate to English and German and routing works fine, however I'm having trouble with switching the dropdown button flag image after I switch the language.

This is how my Dropdown component looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DropdownLink from './DropdownLink/DropdownLink';

import FlagEn from '../../../assets/images/lang/flag-en.svg';
import FlagDe from '../../../assets/images/lang/flag-de.svg';

class Dropdown extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            showMenu: false,
        };

        this.showMenu = this.showMenu.bind(this);
        this.closeMenu = this.closeMenu.bind(this);
    }

    showMenu(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ showMenu: true }, () => {
            document.addEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);

        });
    }

    closeMenu(event) {    
        if (!this.dropdownMenu.contains(event.target) || this.dropdownMenu.contains(event.target)) {

            this.setState({ showMenu: false }, () => {
                document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
            });  

        }
    }

    render() {
        const dropdownLinks = [
            { href: '../en', linkText: 'English', linkImg: FlagEn, imgAlt: 'English' },
            { href: '../de', linkText: 'Deutsch', linkImg: FlagDe, imgAlt: 'Deutsch' }
        ];
        let dropdownMenuShow = null;
        if (this.state.showMenu) {
            dropdownMenuShow = <div 
                className="dropdown-menu" 
                ref={(element) => {
                    this.dropdownMenu = element;
                }}>
                {dropdownLinks.map(dropdownLink => (
                    <DropdownLink 
                        onClick={this.showMenu}
                        href={dropdownLink.href} 
                        linkText={dropdownLink.linkText} 
                        key={dropdownLink.linkText} 
                        linkImg={dropdownLink.linkImg} 
                        imgAlt={dropdownLink.imgAlt} />
                ))}
            </div>
        }
        return (
            <div className="dropdown">
                <button className="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" onClick={this.showMenu}>
                    <img src={FlagEn} alt="english" />
                </button>
                {dropdownMenuShow}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Dropdown;
```

and this is my DropdownLink component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const dropdownLink = (props) => (
    <NavLink className="dropdown-item" to={props.href} exact>
        <img src={props.linkImg} alt={props.imgAlt} />
        <span>{props.linkText}</span>
    </NavLink>
);

export default dropdownLink;
```

Is there a way to switch the dropdown button's flag image so that US flag is there when English language is selected and German flag for the German language?
Links are routing to "/en" and "/de".

Answer (score 0):

here is a rough revision of your class that uses the local state to store the selected language (since you didn't specify how you're storing it)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DropdownLink from './DropdownLink/DropdownLink';

import FlagEn from '../../../assets/images/lang/flag-en.svg';
import FlagDe from '../../../assets/images/lang/flag-de.svg';

class Dropdown extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.dropdownLinks = [
            { href: '../en', linkText: 'English', linkImg: FlagEn, imgAlt: 'English' },
            { href: '../de', linkText: 'Deutsch', linkImg: FlagDe, imgAlt: 'Deutsch' }
        ];

        this.state = {
            showMenu: false,
            selectedLanguage: this.dropdownLinks[0]
        };

        this.showMenu = this.showMenu.bind(this);
        this.setLanguage = this.setLanguage.bind(this);
        this.closeMenu = this.closeMenu.bind(this);
    }

    showMenu(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ showMenu: true }, () => {
            document.addEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);

        });
    }

    setLanguage(language) {
        this.setState({selectedLanguage: language})
    }

    closeMenu(event) {    
        if (!this.dropdownMenu.contains(event.target) || this.dropdownMenu.contains(event.target)) {

            this.setState({ showMenu: false }, () => {
                document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
            });  

        }
    }

    render() {
        let dropdownMenuShow = null;
        if (this.state.showMenu) {
            dropdownMenuShow = <div 
                className="dropdown-menu" 
                ref={(element) => {
                    this.dropdownMenu = element;
                }}>
                {this.dropdownLinks.map(dropdownLink => (
                    <DropdownLink 
                        onClick={() => this.setLanguage(dropdownLink)}
                        href={dropdownLink.href} 
                        linkText={dropdownLink.linkText} 
                        key={dropdownLink.linkText} 
                        linkImg={dropdownLink.linkImg} 
                        imgAlt={dropdownLink.imgAlt} />
                ))}
            </div>
        }
        return (
            <div className="dropdown">
                <button className="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" onClick={this.showMenu}>
                    <img src={this.state.selectedLanguage.linkImg} alt="english" />
                </button>
                {dropdownMenuShow}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Dropdown;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function to update the image your showing in the button and pass that down into the  component.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import DropdownLink from './DrowdownLink';

    export default class Test extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            super();

            this.state = {
                showMenu: false,
                buttonFlag: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQb9JntXqHxGA9U_q4nJYzi1f5lzHWKReT3OwYNyydpNuFd9B0e'
            };

            this.showMenu = this.showMenu.bind(this);
            this.closeMenu = this.closeMenu.bind(this);
            this.updateFlag = this.updateFlag.bind(this);
        }

        showMenu(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            this.setState({ showMenu: true }, () => {
                document.addEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);

            });
        }

        closeMenu(event) {
            if (!this.dropdownMenu.contains(event.target) || this.dropdownMenu.contains(event.target)) {

                this.setState({ showMenu: false }, () => {
                    document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
                });

            }
        }

        updateFlag(link) {
            console.log(link);
            this.setState({ buttonFlag: link })
        }

        render() {
            const dropdownLinks = [
                { href: '../en', linkText: 'English', linkImg: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQb9JntXqHxGA9U_q4nJYzi1f5lzHWKReT3OwYNyydpNuFd9B0e', imgAlt: 'English' },
                { href: '../de', linkText: 'Deutsch', linkImg: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRDqHreeGXhpRqWg8YwpjAPfv6_HXy7nEatEU8ec2KWxtI0LnBRLQ', imgAlt: 'Deutsch' }
            ];
            let dropdownMenuShow = null;
            if (this.state.showMenu) {
                dropdownMenuShow = <div
                    className="dropdown-menu"
                    ref={(element) => {
                        this.dropdownMenu = element;
                    }}>
                    {dropdownLinks.map(dropdownLink => (
                        <DropdownLink
                            onClick={this.showMenu}
                            href={dropdownLink.href}
                            linkText={dropdownLink.linkText}
                            key={dropdownLink.linkText}
                            linkImg={dropdownLink.linkImg}
                            updateFlag={this.updateFlag}
                            imgAlt={dropdownLink.imgAlt} />
                    ))}
                </div>
            }
            return (
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <button className="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" onClick={this.showMenu}>
                        <img src={this.state.buttonFlag} alt="english" />
                    </button>
                    {dropdownMenuShow}
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

The src for the button is now pulling from state and the state is updated from inside the DropdownLink component with a function we pass in as a prop called **updateFlag**. Also I don't have those resources so I just used two links to flag pictures online.

Here is the DropdownLink component

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

    const dropdownLink = (props) => (
        <div className="dropdown-item" exact>
            <img onClick={() => props.updateFlag(props.linkImg)} src={props.linkImg} alt={props.imgAlt} />
            <span>{props.linkText}</span>
        </div>
    );

    export default dropdownLink;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It changes the flag but the US flag is the default button flag if a visitor lands on /de route. This only works after the links are clicked. Can something be done with withRouter in order to tie the flags to the route by default?